# I keep getting a not defined error when trying to use and object in an if statement

Tags: python, class

I created an employee class and then created two employee objects from this class. I then created and new file and imported this class and objects into my main class. When i try to call my employee object inside a function i get "Alexis" not defined when i call on this function. Im not quite sure why its doing that?

```
class employee(object):

  def  __init__(self,name,pay_rate,total_hours,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday):
    self.name = name
    self.pay_rate = pay_rate
    self.total_hours = total_hours
    self.monday = monday
    self.tuesday = tuesday
    self.wednesday = wednesday
    self.thursday = thursday
    self.friday = friday
    self.saturday = saturday
    self.sunday = sunday


  def weekly_total(self):
    self.total_weekly_hours = self.monday + self.tuesday + self.wednesday + self.thursday + self.friday + self.saturday + self.sunday        
    self.emp_name()
    if self.total_weekly_hours > self.total_hours:
        print "\n  Your hours this week are:", self.total_weekly_hours,"\n"


  def emp_name(self):
    print "\n  Current employee is: ",self.name


    Alexis = employee("Alexis ",2.25,40,"\n  morning\n","  morning\n","     afternoon\n","  OFF\n","  OFF\n","  afternoon\n","  OFF\n") 
    Casey = employee("Casey",2.25,40,5,5,3,50,0,2,13)
```

AND

```
   from Employ_Class import employee 

   class mainmenu:

    def __init__(self):
    print "inside init"
    self.options_menu()

def options_menu(self):
    print "  1. Employee clock in\n","  2. Administrator options"
    self.menu_select = input()
    if self.menu_select == 1: 
        self.enter_name = raw_input("  Please enter an employee name for clock in\t")
    elif self.menu_select == 2:
        self.admin_pass = raw_input("Please enter your admin password")
        if self.admin_pass == "x":
            Alexis.weekly_total()
        else:
            print "Wrong password"
```

mainmenu()

Comment: Please correct your code indentation in question.

Comment: Why don't you move your declarations of Alexis and Casey to the other file?

Comment: Why is `Alexis` defined inside `emp_name()`? Is class `mainmenu` intended to be inside class `employee`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line

```
Alexis.weekly_total()
```

You reference a variable `Alexis` before defining it. You should probably search for an `employee` instance, then call `.weekly_total()` on that.

Comment: I assumed since it was assigned in my employee class i was good to go but that is not the case i guess. How would one go about searching for and instance of employee?

Comment: If you want to just access the Alexis variable then import it with `from Employ_Class import employee, Alexis`. If you want to store multiple employees and search for them then you should put them in a list, or dict.

Comment: thanks buddy that is what I'm currently doing i appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the imports:
from Employ_Class import Alexis